# SignalR with vNext

Tags: c#, asp.net, signalr, asp.net-core

I am having difficult time to use SignalR in vNext project (epmty template).

Firsty I added SignalR.Server dependency to my project.json file and it looks now like this:

```
{
    "webroot": ".",
    "dependencies": {
        "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.IIS": "1.0.0-beta3",
        "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.WebListener": "1.0.0-*",
        "Microsoft.AspNet.StaticFiles": "1.0.0-*",
        "Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Server": "3.0.0-*",
        "Serilog": "1.4.113.0"
},
    "commands": {
        "web": "Microsoft.AspNet.Hosting server=Microsoft.AspNet.Server.WebListener server.urls=http://localhost:5002"
    },
    "frameworks": {
        "dnx451": {
            "dependencies": {
                "Microsoft.Framework.Logging.Serilog": "1.0.0-*"
            }
        },
        "dnxcore50": { }
    }
}
```

And then I wanted to map the SignalR in my Startup.cs (as i found somwhere on git)

```
 public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddSignalR(options =>
        {
            options.Hubs.EnableDetailedErrors = true;
        });
    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
    {
#if DNX451
        string OutputTemplate = "{SourceContext} {Timestamp:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff zzz} [{Level}] {Message}{NewLine}{Exception}";

        var serilog = new LoggerConfiguration()
            .MinimumLevel.Verbose()
            .WriteTo.RollingFile(@".\SignalR-Log-{Date}.txt", outputTemplate: OutputTemplate);

        loggerFactory.AddSerilog(serilog);
#endif

        app.UseFileServer();

        app.UseSignalR<RawConnection>("/raw-connection");
        app.UseSignalR();
    }
```

, but when i add at the top:

```
using Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR;
```

I get error:

> The type or namespace name 'SignalR' does not exist in the namespace >'Microsoft.AspNet' (are you missing an assembly reference?)  VersaWeb.ASP.NET >5.0   c:\Users\Jakub\documents\visual studio >2015\Projects\VersaWeb\src\VersaWeb\Startup.cs

And I am stuck right now.

---

EDIT:

The problem had to be with project.json becouse when i copied the one from music store the problem vanished.

Here is my current project.json (probably some of dependencies are not needed so i am gonna further test it)

```
{
"authors": [
    "author"
],
"description": "your description here",
"version": "1.0.0",
"compilationOptions": { "warningsAsErrors": true, "define": [ "DEMO", "TESTING" ] },
"code": [
    "**/*.cs"
],
"bundleExclude": "*.cmd",
"webroot": "wwwroot",
"dependencies": {
    "EntityFramework.SqlServer": "7.0.0-beta3",
    "EntityFramework.InMemory": "7.0.0-beta3", // For Mono.
    "Kestrel": "1.0.0-beta3",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Diagnostics": "1.0.0-beta3",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Diagnostics.Entity": "7.0.0-beta3",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework": "3.0.0-beta3",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc": "6.0.0-beta3",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Security.OpenIdConnect": "1.0.0-beta3",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.IIS": "1.0.0-beta3",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.WebListener": "1.0.0-beta3",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Server": "3.0.0-beta3",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.StaticFiles": "1.0.0-beta3",
    "Microsoft.Framework.Cache.Memory": "1.0.0-beta3",
    "Microsoft.Framework.CodeGenerators.Mvc": "1.0.0-beta3",
    "Microsoft.Framework.ConfigurationModel.Json": "1.0.0-beta3",
    "Microsoft.Framework.Logging.Console": "1.0.0-beta3"
},
"commands": {
    "gen": "Microsoft.Framework.CodeGeneration",
    "kestrel": "Microsoft.AspNet.Hosting --server Kestrel --server.urls http://localhost:5004",
    "run": "run server.urls=http://localhost:5003",
    "web": "Microsoft.AspNet.Hosting --server Microsoft.AspNet.Server.WebListener --server.urls http://localhost:5002"
},
"frameworks": {
    "aspnet50": { },
    "aspnetcore50": { }
}
}
```

Comment: Maybe the error applies only to dnxcore? Try to comment out ""dnxcore50": { }" in project.json to verify that. Also, checkout [MusicStore sample](https://github.com/aspnet/MusicStore/tree/master/src/MusicStore), which uses SignalR. I am also using SignalR in my vnext project (although with kre, not the new dnx stuff), so it is definitely doable.

Comment: I commented dnxcore50 and nothing happened but now i have downloaded musicstore and I will check and compare my files with stores

Comment: MusicStore sample works - and acording to web console web sockets were correctly opened - i will now inspect code

Comment: @qbik - you can now write reply and i will mark as answere - music store sample helped me a lot :) Thanks

Comment: Great! Could you write, what was wrong in your project and what helped?

Comment: sure, i just edited the question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Checkout [MusicStore sample](https://github.com/aspnet/MusicStore/tree/master/src/MusicStore), which uses SignalR. I am also using SignalR in my vnext project (although with kre, not the new dnx stuff), so it is definitely doable.

Comment: It probably did in the past but I can't find the reference in the project.json file https://github.com/aspnet/MusicStore/blob/dev/src/MusicStore/project.json

Comment: Indeed it seems like they [removed SignalR](https://github.com/aspnet/MusicStore/issues/529) and also [moved MusicStore.Spa](https://github.com/aspnet/MusicStore/issues/537) to [Entropy](https://github.com/aspnet/Entropy) repo.
I have put together a simple sample of using SignalR in aspnet5 here: https://github.com/heavymetaldev/aspnet5-signalr

Comment: Cool! On MSDN I also found a sample that can be downloaded here https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/The-ASPNET-vNext-Real-Time-b1d27fe4 . (Check out the funny build instructions) This uses the Stable 2.2.0 version of SignalR as the 3.0 version is delayed to Q3 later this year (https://github.com/aspnet/Home/wiki/Roadmap)

Answer (score 2):

Looking at your initial `project.json` it was probably the fact you were attempting to target `dnx451` but running against the wrong .NET development runtime.

The main thing I found when working with this vNext stuff is that all of your references need to be on the same level *beta3/beta4/beta5* and your .NET runtime must match (`frameworks` in `project.json`). I believe `beta3` used `aspnet50` and since the `beta4` rename it is now `dnx451`.

It is worth running `dnvm list` on the command line and seeing what is installed and what is set to the 'default' alias as this is what Visual Studio will use when running your application (unless overriden in the solution `global.json` file).